# Do something automatically after class definition?

Tags: python-3.x, metaprogramming

What I would like is the following:

```
lst = []

class Awesome:
  """This is my magical super class."""

  ...

class Inherits(Awesome):
  """Awesome does awesome stuff with Inherits."""
  name = "Stack"

class InheritsAgain(Awesome):
  name = "Overflow"

print(lst)
#: ['Stack', 'Overflow']
```

So basically, when the classes `Inherits` and `InheritsAgain` are defined, because they
inherit from `Awesome`, `Awesome` has some metaclass magic (or whatever), that reads
the attribute `name` from the inheriting class, and appends it to `lst`.

I've looked at the meta-classes in Python, but I'm not sure exactly how this would fit together.

Is this possible in Python? And if it is, how would you go about it?

**Edit:**

Let's add to the above example, so that this also works:

```
class AndAgain(Awesome):
  name = "/root/path/<name>/<id>"

  def go():
    pass
```

I want the whole class `AndAgain` to be defined, so that I can inspect and see that `name` exists with the value `"/root/path/<name>/<id>"`, and the function `go()` also exists.

Comment: I feel obligated to say that having a class rely on/manipulate a global variable is not portable and can get confusing if your project gets too big.

Comment: This is more complicated than I thought at first. Are you sure you _have_ to do it that way? Couldn't this be an instance of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: The global variable is just an example. ;-) I hope you don't think I would really name my classes like I did. The actual application is a way to automatically add endpoints of a REST API. Thought it would be nice if I didn't have to always write `api.add_resource(ClassName, "/location")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = []

class AwesomeMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict):
        if cls != 'Awesome':
            lst.append(cls)
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict)

class Awesome(metaclass=AwesomeMeta):
  """This is my magical super class."""


class Stack(Awesome):
  """Awesome does awesome stuff with Inherits."""


class Overflow(Awesome):
    """More awesomely stuff!"""

print(lst)
```

And to show looking inside the class:

```
lst = []

class AwesomeMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict):
        if 'name' in classdict:
            lst.append(classdict['name'])
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict)

class Awesome(metaclass=AwesomeMeta):
    """This is my magical super class."""


class Inherits(Awesome):
    """Awesome does awesome stuff with Inherits."""

    name = 'Stack'


class InheritsAgain(Awesome):
    """More awesomely stuff!"""

    name = 'Overflow'

class AndAgain(Awesome):
    name = "/root/path/<name>/<id>"

    def go():
        pass

print(lst)
```

Comment: Perhaps I mislead with my simplistic example of using the attribute name. What I want is something arbitrary, like a regex pattern that I can extract from subclasses.

Comment: @cassava:  Not at all -- this gives you the tools;  add whatever you want/need in the metaclass `__new__` to inspect the class that is being created and modify it or anything else.

Comment: I assume you mean `class Awesome(object)`. Does `Awesome` really need to inherit `object`? Doesn't everything implicitly inherit `object`?

Comment: @cassava: You didn't tag the question as Python3 so I wrote Python 2 code.  :)  In Python 2 not everything inherits from object.  And es, I did mean `class Awesome(object)`.  :)

Answer (score 1):

One can use metaclasses

```
class AwesomeMeta(type):
    lst = []
    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict):
        if 'name' in classdict:
            metacls.lst.append(classdict['name'])
        return super(AwesomeMeta, metacls).__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict)

class Awesome(object):
    """This is my magical super class."""
    __metaclass__ = AwesomeMeta


class Inherits(Awesome):
    """Awesome does awesome stuff with Inherits."""
    name = 'Stack'


class InheritsAgain(Awesome):
    """More awesomely stuff!"""
    name = 'Overflow'

print InheritsAgain.lst, Inherits.lst, Awesome.lst
```

or one can use `__subclasses__` method

```
print [i.name for i in Awesome.__subclasses__()]
```

or One can use class decorator

```
lst = []
def cls_decorator(cls):
    lst.append(cls.name)
    return cls

@cls_decorator
class Awesome(object):
    """This is my magical super class."""
    name = 'Awesome'


@cls_decorator
class Inherits(Awesome):
    """Awesome does awesome stuff with Inherits."""
    name = 'Stack'


@cls_decorator
class InheritsAgain(Awesome):
    """More awesomely stuff!"""
    name = 'Overflow'
```

Solution should depend on what are You going to do